# How to compare ordered dictionaries Keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following  Dictionary

```
{"data":[{"shift":"day","bus_type":"ac","seat_price_for_travel_agent":"900","seat_price_for_user":"1000","seat_price_for_foreigner":"1100"},
{"shift":"night","bus_type":"deluxe","seat_price_for_travel_agent":"900","seat_price_for_user":"1000","seat_price_for_foreigner":"1100"}]}
```

I am having problem on comparing two shifts i.e day and night?
Is there any way to compare these shifts.
Sorry If question seems irrelevant.

Comment: please define "compare" in a more concrete manner (same keys? same keys and values?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over dictionaries almost the same as iterating over lists. You can use the `zip()` function to create tuples to easily access the items of two data structures at once. Use `.items()`, `.keys()` or `.values()` respectively.

```
dic = {
    "data":
    [{"shift":"day","bus_type":"ac","seat_price_for_travel_agent":"900","seat_price_for_user":"1000","seat_price_for_foreigner":"1100"},
   {"shift":"night","bus_type":"deluxe","seat_price_for_travel_agent":"900","seat_price_for_user":"1000","seat_price_for_foreigner":"1100"}]
}
```

Access the complete dictionary entries:

```
for (day, night) in zip(dic["data"][0].items(), dic["data"][1].items()):
    print(day)
    print(night)
```

will give you:

```
('shift', 'day')
('shift', 'night')
('bus_type', 'ac')
('bus_type', 'deluxe')
('seat_price_for_travel_agent', '900')
('seat_price_for_travel_agent', '900')
('seat_price_for_user', '1000')
('seat_price_for_user', '1000')
('seat_price_for_foreigner', '1100')
('seat_price_for_foreigner', '1100')
```

Access only the keys (equivalent to omitting `.keys()`):

```
for (day, night) in zip(dic["data"][0].keys(), dic["data"][1].keys()):
    print(day)
    print(night)
```

Will give you:

```
shift
shift
bus_type
bus_type
seat_price_for_travel_agent
seat_price_for_travel_agent
seat_price_for_user
seat_price_for_user
seat_price_for_foreigner
seat_price_for_foreigner
```

Access only the values:

```
for (day, night) in zip(dic["data"][0].values(), dic["data"][1].values()):
    print(day)
    print(night)
```

Will give you:

```
day
night
ac
deluxe
900
900
1000
1000
1100
1100
```

I think you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pairwise compare the values for the same keys you can start with a method like this:

```
dict1, dict2 = {"data":[{"shift":"day","bus_type":"ac","seat_price_for_travel_agent":"900","seat_price_for_user":"1000","seat_price_for_foreigner":"1100"},
    ...: {"shift":"night","bus_type":"deluxe","seat_price_for_travel_agent":"900","seat_price_for_user":"1000","seat_price_for_foreigner":"1100"}]}['data']
```

If you are sure that the dicts have the same keys, you can compare them pairwise like this:

```
[ (k,dict1[k]==dict2[k]) for k in dict1.keys()]

Out: 
[('shift', False),
 ('bus_type', False),
 ('seat_price_for_travel_agent', True),
 ('seat_price_for_user', True),
 ('seat_price_for_foreigner', True)]
```